# How to get local IP address behind the proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using this extension method to track the user's IP address:

```
public static string GetUser_IP_Address(string input = null)
{
    string visitorsIpAddr = string.Empty;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
    {
         visitorsIpAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress))
    {
         visitorsIpAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    }

    if (input != null)
    {
        return string.Format("Your IP address is {0}.", visitorsIpAddr);
    }
    return visitorsIpAddr;
}
```

Above code gives me actual address on computers without proxy, But those who have proxy setting it gives me the IP address of the proxy server.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StackExchange DataExplorer App](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/StackOverflowController.cs) also determines the IP address of the user behind proxy using following function. You can check it out.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// When a client IP can't be determined
        /// </summary>
        public const string UnknownIP = "0.0.0.0"; 

        private static readonly Regex _ipAddress = new Regex(@"\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$",
                                                         RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

       /// <summary>
       /// returns true if this is a private network IP
       /// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network
       /// </summary>
         private static bool IsPrivateIP(string s)
         {
            return (s.StartsWith("192.168.") || s.StartsWith("10.") || s.StartsWith("127.0.0."));
         }
        public static string GetRemoteIP(NameValueCollection ServerVariables)
        {
            string ip = ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; // could be a proxy -- beware
            string ipForwarded = ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

            // check if we were forwarded from a proxy
            if (ipForwarded.HasValue())
            {
                ipForwarded = _ipAddress.Match(ipForwarded).Value;
                if (ipForwarded.HasValue() && !IsPrivateIP(ipForwarded))
                    ip = ipForwarded;
            }

            return ip.HasValue() ? ip : UnknownIP;
        }
```

Here `HasValue()` is an extension defined in another class as below:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool HasValue(this string s)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
    }
}
```