# How to get IP address behind proxy in delphi

Tags: delphi, soap, proxy, ip-address

I need get the client IP adress from SOAP request behind proxy for filtering and logging, but I cannot get it to work. The "WebDispatcher.Request.RemoteAddr" always returns only the proxy server IP address.

I'm using Delphi 10.3 and the application and API is already running in production long time ago, so it is not option to add the ip address as parameter from client side.

I found similiar question for C# where seems it works like in PHP, which I had running before on the server.
[How to get local IP address behind the proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297517/how-to-get-local-ip-address-behind-the-proxy)

I tried following code:

```
function TSOAPservice.SOAP_test(id: Integer; user : String): String; stdcall;
var ip_adr : String;
    WebDispatcher: IWebDispatcherAccess;
begin
  if Supports(GetSOAPWebModule, IWebDispatcherAccess, WebDispatcher) then
  begin
    ip_adr := WebDispatcher.Request.GetFieldByName('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    if ip_adr ='' then
      ip_adr := WebDispatcher.Request.RemoteAddr;
  end;
end;
```

Is there any way to get the IP address from SOAP call with proxy in delphi?

Comment: Unless the proxy (and what kind of proxy are you using, exactly?) explicitly adds the client's IP to the SOAP request, then no. Are you actually using SOAP over HTTP? If so, are you implying that the `X-Fordwarded-For` header is empty? (Have you tried `'X-Fordwarded-For'` instead of `'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'`?) Have you tried inspecting all of the available HTTP headers?

Comment: About he proxy - it's just server that convert the http**s** request to http port. 
So I inspected all of the available HTTP headers, with no usable data, all the interesting headers returns empty string.
Could the HTTP headers from Response object contains the origin IP address? To know where send the soap response.

Comment: If you control the proxy have it add the information you need to the request as it passes it on.

Comment: No, the Response object will not have the original client IP, since the server is not sending the response to the client, but to the proxy. The proxy knows which client sent the request and will route the response accordingly. So, the ONLY way your server can know the original IP is if the proxy adds the original IP to the request headers when forwarding ithe request. Either in `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Originating-IP`, or other similar header.